# Significato dell'espressione "Vite noiose, parchi monotematici" in inglese

Tags: meaning, translation, phrases

Se va bene, chiederò in inglese, ma se contro le regole posso scrivere di nuovo.

For context; it's a particular song (["21 grammi" di Fedez](https://www.rockit.it/duplici/canzone/21-grammi/226862)), translating to someone it's okay but to translate the significance of this expression, I don't know, even to really 'get' it, I don't know.

> Ci hanno sciolto le certezze dentro al bicchiere
>
> Ora ho più ghiaccio nel cuore che dentro al Jack Daniels
>
> Cuori meccanici per noi sociopatici
>
> **Vite noiose, parchi monotematici**
>
> Amiamoci, perdiamoci, faranno delle indagini
>
> Finché le nostre lacrime non romperanno gli argini

So, if it's possible that it means something more profound, and important. I would like to hear some ideas.

Also, is this an expression used regularly or it's a 'poetic license'?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Grazie, vedo sempre che sei con la risposta per tutto! ;)

Comment: It's not everyday that “Fedez” and “profound” are used in the same paragraph.

Comment: @DaG while I feel your sympathy, Federica Abbate was a writter on the song so I had some faith that it was the lyrics and not the performer who could deliver a profound expression ;)

Comment: Sorry, who's Federica Abbate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any profound meaning in  such expression. "Vite noiose" means "boring lifes", the Italian expression "parco tematico" would translate as "theme park" and "parchi tematici" is its plural. "Monotematico" means "monothematic", so I suppose that with the expression "parchi monotematici" (which is not a common Italian expression at all, but I wouldn't qualified it as "poetic") the author of the song has imagined theme parks in which every attraction is similar to each other so as to render them monotonous, boring and without any interest at all.

Comment: Nice, your last sentence is the perfect description, one final question I guess, there is a word to describe this action; of using a general image to describe something more broad ?! Its like 'allegoria' ? Or something else ? I'm forgetting all my Italian :(

Comment: @Pogrindis:  I think you are referring to a [metaphor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metaphor) ("metafora" in Italian).

Comment: I was thinking this too, but it doesn't feel like the right word, there is one in my mind, even in english which is specific for the action of painting an image in someones head to point a context. But, metaphor is as good as word as any!
Thank you again, more dumb questions on the way I am sure!

Comment: @Pogrindis:  Well, "allegoria" means [allegory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allegory).